# different versions for pip and sudo pip

Tags: python, pip

pip --version

pip 18.1 from /home/myhome/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

sudo pip --version

pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)

How can I change the sudo pip --version also to python 2.7 ?

Comment: I think your question is how to change the default version of python, not pip, used by sudo/root.

Comment: Depending on your distro, you can also use `pip2` or `pip3` in the terminal to invoke the version you want.

Comment: @del sudo python returns 2.7. So, the problem is not in the python version.

Comment: @osolmaz pip2 did the trick.